# Python: Remove html tag including content if next sibling is identical

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

If I have something like this:

```
<div>
<a>Link</a>
</div>
<div>
<a>Link</a>
</div>
```

I would like to remove one of the div tags (including all content and child tags), because the two div tags, including their content, are the same. Only tags that are next to each other should be compared and eventually one of them removed. That should also work recursevly. For example if I have something like this:

```
<div>
<a>Link</a>
<a>Link</a>
</div>
<div>
<a>Link</a>
</div>
```

Only one of the a links from the first div should be removed.

I have tried to solve the problem with BeautifulSoup, with the following code:

```
def removeDuplicates(items):
    for item in items:
        if item==item.nextSibling:
            item.extract()
        else:
            children = item.findChildren()
            removeDuplicates(children)

body = soup.find('body')
items = body.findChildren()
removeDuplicates(items)
```

But the code takes ages to execute.

Is there any quick way to remove duplicate tags as I described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was working slow because I assumed that `.findChildren()` only gets direct children (first level below), but it actually gets all children (from all levels). Because of that, the solution was to remove the following lines from my code:

```
    else:
        children = item.findChildren()
        removeDuplicates(children)
```